# Draw Smaller moveable Images on big image loaed on Kinectjs canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, layer, stage

I loaded a big image on to a  kinectjs canvas.
Code below:

```
   <div id ="imgarea" ></div>
   var imageToCanvas = function(){
   var stages = new Kinetic.Stage({
   container: "imgarea",

   });

   var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

    var imageobj = new Image();
    imageobj.onload = function(){
    var img = new Kinetic.Image({
     x: 10,
     y: 10,
     image: imageobj,
   });
   layer.add(img);
   stages.add(layer);
 };
 imageobj.src = "foto/next.png";
  console.log(imageobj);
}; 

 $(document).ready( function(){
  imageToCanvas();
});
```

please how can i draw smaller moveable and resizeable images(icons)with the onclick event on the big image i drew earlier.i tried doing that with the following code:

```
     <Img src="testImage.jpg" onclick="var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();  drawImage(this.src);"   />
```

But sadly its not working :(....somebody please help. Thanks

Comment: Any answers Please.Thanks again